# Is it possible to update the properties of a table with Flask + SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I created a table model that has a 'unique=true' property (flask code)

```
class Books(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

This was a mistake and I want to change the unique property to false (or just remove it..).

```
class Books(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
```

How do I re-create the table via flask-python code?
Offcourse, I can drop the table and rebuild it with `db.create_all()`, or do the same via SQL directly on the database, or change it with an SQL command.

Is it possible doing it with the python-[sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html) way? (I really like using the python command line) - Preferably just with a small edit without dropping the data in the table.

Comment: https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**yes it's possible.**
**you need to learn migration:**
[Flask Migration Example](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/#local-migration)